# 'Incorrect Padding' error while using google.oauth2 id_token.verify_oauth2_token() in Django

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am trying to verify a user's submitted google authentication JWT from a React frontend to my Django backend. I have my frontend POST a request to the backend with the JWT, and then my backend extracts it from the request and processes it through google's recommend token authentication [found here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth). My problem is that each time I process a JWT received from my frontend through id_token.verify_ouath2_token(), an error about 'incorrect padding' is raised ultimately stemming from the base64 encoding of the token.

When testing this manually by copy-pasting the token I have extracted from the POST request, however, it works perfectly fine and does not raise an error. So somewhere in my handling of the post request something goes wrong, but I'm not sure what. I have tried decoding the POST request in utf-8 and ascii, and simply leaving the JWT in the bytes form that I extracted it as. All of these throw the same error, and I'm left pretty confused.

Here is my code:
views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.body.decode("ascii")) # For decoding. By copy/pasting this output into id_token.verify_oauth2_token instead of the token variable, the function returns successfully
        try:
            token = request.body.decode("ascii")
            # Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
            idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), "MY CLIENT ID")

    # ID token is valid. Get the user's Google Account ID from the decoded token.
            userid = idinfo['sub']
            return(HttpResponse(userid))
        except ValueError as e:
            # Invalid token
            print(e)
            return(HttpResponse("Failure"))
    else:
        pass
```

and the traceback

```
  File "C:\Users\E\Google Drive\Projects\Django Project\Website\BackEnd\test\Main\views.py", line 80, in login
    idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), "MY CLIENT ID")
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\id_token.py", line 147, in verify_oauth2_token
    id_token, request, audience=audience, certs_url=_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CERTS_URL
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\google\oauth2\id_token.py", line 126, in verify_token
    return jwt.decode(id_token, certs=certs, audience=audience)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\google\auth\jwt.py", line 230, in decode
    header, payload, signed_section, signature = _unverified_decode(token)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\google\auth\jwt.py", line 148, in _unverified_decode
    signature = _helpers.padded_urlsafe_b64decode(signature)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\google\auth\_helpers.py", line 215, in padded_urlsafe_b64decode
    return base64.urlsafe_b64decode(padded)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\base64.py", line 133, in urlsafe_b64decode
    return b64decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\E\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation I figured it out. It looks like request.body.decode("ascii") ended up producing the JWT encased in double quotes, and the double quotes were what was causing the problem. After stripping them from the string it works perfectly.

Final code in views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            token = request.body.decode("ascii").strip("\"") 
            # Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
            idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), "MY CLIENT ID")
```